# How many times does this curve cut the plane $y=2$?

Tags: calculus, curves, parametrization

> The curve L is given by the parametrization: 
> $x(t)=t\cos(2t), y(t)=t\sin(2t), z(t)=\frac{4}{3}t\sqrt{t}$ while $0 \le t \le 3\pi$. 
> How many times does this curve cut the plane $y=2$?

I'm not sure if there's a fixed way to solve these type of questions, but what I thought about is if L is gonna cut $y=2$, then that's whenever $t\sin(2t)=2$, but tbh I got a little stuck in how should I find $t$ values from this equation?
Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think you should try and solve $t \sin (2t) = 2$. Rather one loop of the helix is $\pi$. So for $0 \leq t \leq 3\pi$, at $t = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{9\pi}{4}$, the curve intersects $y-$axis on the positive side. $y = \frac{\pi}{4} \lt 2$ the first time it intersects y-axis on positive side. But next two times $y \gt 2$ which means it would have crossed the plane four times.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for the help, but to be honest you lost me from when you said helix, I imagine helix to be $x=cost, y=sint, z=t$. I didn't quite get the idea :(.

Comment: Yes sorry, don't focus on the helix part. with $t$ being there, I kind of see it as a helix with increasing radius as $z$ increases ($t$ increases) with radius being zero at the origin. Focus on the rest of what I said.

Comment: What is the value of $y$ at $t = \frac{\pi}{4}$? Is it less than $2$ or more?

Comment: How did you find $t=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},..$?

Comment: $x = t \cos (2t), y = t \sin (2t)$ and $t$ is always positive. So when would the curve cross y-axis on the positive side? when $2t = \frac{\pi}{2}, (2 \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}), (4 \pi + \frac{\pi}{2})$, right? As, $x = 0$ on those points and $y$ is positive.

Comment: refresh to see my updated comment. Also note that $z$ is increasing so when I say it crosses y-axis, it does not actually intersect but if you see from above, you see it crossing y-axis.

Comment: I'm starting to get the idea now of the crosses of $y$ axis, you're trying to see when it passes the $y=2$ and start counting, but I still don't get how you counted the number of intersections with the plane $y=2$ from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127169/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).